# How does multiple install command in a single npm statement work?

Tags: node.js, npm

Hy

Can someone explain how to read this line `npm install -g gulp bower && npm install && bower install`

AFAIU, I know first part of the above installs both gulp and bower `npm install -g gulp bower` however I'm not sure abt the rest of that statement `&& npm install && bower install`

thanks

Comment: Globally install gulp and bower, then install local npm dependencies, then install local bower dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`npm install -g gulp bower` this line will install gulp and bower globally.

`npm install` will install all the packages locally that are defined in package.json. [Refer](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

`bower install` will install the packages locally that are defined in bower.json. [Refer](https://bower.io/#install-packages)

The `&&` is used to concat each of the commands to run one after another

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` just chains the commands one after the other. So it is like you have

```
npm install -g gulp bower
npm install
bower install
```

`npm install` will install dependencies listed in package.json.

`bower install` will install dependencies listed in bower.json.